# i get errors in for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I am having errors in my `for` loop and I wonder why is that:

```
for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)

substitution.c:24:25: error: expected expression
        for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)
                        ^
substitution.c:24:44: error: expected ')'
        for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)
                                           ^
substitution.c:24:13: note: to match this '('
        for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)
            ^
substitution.c:24:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)
                                             ^
substitution.c:24:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
        for (int i = 0; char a = 'a'; i < n; i++; a++)
```

edit :

```
when i use for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
i get:
substitution.c:24:25: error: expected identifier or '('
        for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
                        ^
substitution.c:24:25: error: expected ';' in 'for' statement specifier
substitution.c:24:25: error: expected expression
substitution.c:24:44: error: expected ')'
        for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
                                           ^
substitution.c:24:13: note: to match this '('
        for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
            ^
substitution.c:24:46: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
        for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
                                             ^
substitution.c:24:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'a'
        for (int i = 0, char a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
                                                  ^
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a `for` loop with 2 different variables? In that case you need to learn when to use a comma `,` and when to use a semi-colon  `;`

Comment: You can't declare different type of variables in the loop, all your variables you declare in the loop must be of a single type. You should probably define `a` before the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From C11 Standards#6.8.5.3 (the for statement)

> 1 The statement

```
      for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body. The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the controlling expression.158)
>
> Footnotes
>
> 158) Thus, clause-1 specifies initialization for the loop, **possibly declaring one or more variables for use in the loop**; the controlling expression, expression-2, specifies an evaluation made before each iteration, such that execution of the loop continues until the expression compares equal to 0; and expression-3 specifies an operation (such as incrementing) that is performed after each iteration.

Also, from C11 Standards#6.7 (Declarations)

> ```
>       declaration:
>              declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
> ```

Note the `;` at the end of declaration.

`clause-1` can be a declaration statement or an expression. If `clause-1` is a declaration, you can declare one or more variable of same type because a declaration ends with `;`. So, you can have -

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
```

The `expression-2` and `expression-3` are the expressions, you can use any valid expression in place of them.

If you are using multiple variables of different types in `for` loop, you can initialise them in `clause-1` provided they should be declared before loop:

```
char a;
int i;
for (i = 0, a = 'a'; i < n; i++, a++)
```

Of course, you can also do

```
char a = 'a';
int i = 0;
for (; i < n; i++, a++)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only have a single declaration clause (declaring one or more variables of a *single* type) in the first part of a `for` loop.  At least one of those variables has to be declared outside the loop.

```
char a = 'a';
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++; a++)
```

Comment: Technically, the declared variables don't need to share a single type. But they do need to share the same declaration specifier list.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, the for loop looks like this:

```
for (expression; expression; expression) statement
```

or

```
for (declaration; expression; expression) statement
```

Typically, it is used like this:

```
for(init; condition; increment) statement
```

You declare more than one variable in init, but they have to be of the same type. A workaround is to declare a struct. Here is a proof of concept:

```
$ cat k.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for(struct {
        int a; char b; double c; } s =
        { .a = 0, .b = 'a', .c = 1.3 };
        s.a < 10;
        s.a++
        )
    {
        s.b+=2;
        s.c+=3;
        printf("%d %c %f\n", s.a, s.b, s.c);
    }
}

$ gcc k.c -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -pedantic

$ ./a.out 
0 c 4.300000
1 e 7.300000
2 g 10.300000
3 i 13.300000
4 k 16.300000
5 m 19.300000
6 o 22.300000
7 q 25.300000
8 s 28.300000
9 u 31.300000
```

IMHO, the above is overkill and not very readable. If you badly want the other variables to be local within the for loop, you can encapsulate in brackets to create a scope like this:

```
{ // Starting bracket
  // Declare variables
for(;;) {
}} // End both for loop and previous scope
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    {   char b = 'a'; 
        double c = 1.3;
    for(int a=0; a<10; a++)
    {
        b+=2;
        c+=3;
        printf("%d %c %f\n", a, b, c);
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop has the form

```
for(initializer; incrementor; test)
{
       }
```

So, only two semicolons. The expressions inside the three parts (initializer, incremental, test) are comma-separated.

Comment: Isn't it `for(initializer; test; incrementor)`?